# Complicated multivariable implicit differentiation problem

Tags: calculus

Given that the surface $x^{6}y^{5}+y^{4}z^{5}+z^{9}x^{7}+4xyz=7$ has the equation $z=f(x,y)$ in a neighborhood of the point (1, 1, 1) with f(x,y) differentiable, find:

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^2}(1,1)$

---

I have already found an intermediate expression:

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{-6x^{5}y^{5}-7z^{9}x^{6}-4yz}{5y^{4}z^{4}+9z^{8}x^{7}+4xy}$

At the point (1, 1), we have that it's value is -17/18. However, I have tried finding the second partial derivative in two different ways, differentiating both sides of the expression and then differentiating the complete quotient, but i get different results and my answer is still wrong. Could someone guide me in the right direction or have an easier method to solve this exercise? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$x^{6}y^{5}+y^{4}z^{5}+z^{9}x^{7}+4xyz=7,~~~z=f(x,y)$$ then $$6x^5y^5+\color{red}{\underline{5z^4z'y^5}}+\color{blue}{\underline{9z^8z'x^7}}+\color{green}{\underline{7z^9x^6}}+4yz+4xyz'=0$$ and so $$30x^5y^5+\color{red}{\underline{20z^3z'^2y^5+5z^4z''y^5}}+\color{blue}{\underline{72z^7z'^2x^7+9z^8z''x^7+63z^8z'x^6}}+\color{green}{\underline{63z^8z'x^6+42z^9x^6}}+4yz'+4yz'+4xyz''=0$$

Comment: Yay! color! (I like your profile update with the cat!)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks!. I learned doing that from you. :-) Yes, I got it from my FB page last night. :-)

Comment: I had the same result as you, but i completely forgot about the minus sign when passing the expression over to the other side (-1114/729)! Thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: @fogvajarash: I am glad. Welcome! :-)